# Reference request on category of sheaves

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, sheaf-theory

Title says it all. I'm fairly certain you can turn shaves of abelian groups or commutative rings into a category, but I'm not sure how we define morphisms, subsheaves, or quotients. Anyone know any textbook that discusses this in detail?

Comment: Vakil's notes on Algebraic Geometry are free and comprehensive. They are great.

Comment: @DonThousand Perfect. Much thanks.